# Increase MMS picture's width and height

Tags: java, android, image, photo, mms

So I have an SMS app and I'm sending MMS pictures. Pictures are resized before sending. I want to change `maxImageWidth` and `maxImageHeight` so the sent pictures will be bigger.

I have a class `BugleCarrierConfigValuesLoader` and a method inside:

```java
/**
 * Loading carrier config values
 *
 * @param subId which SIM to load for
 * @param values the result to add to
 * @return the source of the config, could be "resources" or "resources+system"
 */
private String loadLocked(final int subId, final Bundle values) {
    // Load from resources in earlier platform
    loadFromResources(subId, values);
    if (OsUtil.isAtLeastL()) {
        // Load from system to override if system API exists
        loadFromSystem(subId, values);
        return "resources+system";
    }
    return "resources";
}
```

This method loads values like `maxImageWidth=640` or `maxImageHeight=480`.

I would like to understand why is it done like that. Why can't I just make final static int with maxImageWidth value. Why do I need to load these values from resources or system.

Comment: Probably you can't change those values because the MMS protocol has straight restrictions of the size. Therefore it is *probably* set by user's GSM provider

Comment: The problem is that the values are: maxImageWidth = 640 and maxImageHeight = 480. They values are too small

Comment: It is probably a limit of your GSM provider.

Comment: Not really, 'loadFromResources()' loads from .xml file. If I change value in this file I can easily increase picture's resolution and the image is successfully sent.

Comment: The problem is that this value is overriden by 'loadFromSystem()'. And 'loadFromSystem()' loads values from imms service